# How to load a many file schema into a database?

Tags: sql, oracle, reverse-engineering, hsqldb, ddl

I have been provided with a schema that consists of many DDL SQL files in a folder structure. I have very little background into the workings of this schema. I need the schema to be loaded into a live database for testing and reverse engineering Hibernate classes.

My goals are to:

- Use the schema to build a live HyperSQL database
- Script this process so it can be done with each new schema
- Make the script also work in an Oracle DB

Am I lost down the rabbit hole? Is there a better way to get to a live database? What are the major pitfalls?

Comment: As for the Oracle DB, you can use sqlplus in a script to load your files, `sqlplus <user>/<pswrd>@<db> @ddlFile.sql`

Answer (score 1):

You can use HSQLDB's SqlTool jar to load SQL files into both Oracle and HSQLDB. SqlTool allows you to load the SQL files interactively, or with a script.

See the Guide here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html

To make the schema also work in Oracle, you may have to use the Oracle syntax compatibility mode for HSQLDB. This offers some compatibility, but you may have to modify the DDL in some cases to be compatible with both Oracle and HSQLDB. As HSQLDB has a very rich feature set, based on the SQL Standard, it is generally possible to use Oracle and HSQLDB in tandem.

Comment: The DDL is actually from Oracle and HSQLDB is being used for testing and some development, so I'm hoping to have minimum conflicts.